# InAppPurchase ios Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I'm currently implementing a Phonegap app for android and iOS , now in ios i have requirement to implement Inapppurchase  .

Any one can ans  here with example or ref site.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through [3 Steps Tutorial for PhoneGap In-App Purchase on iOS](http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-in-app-purchase-on-ios/). This has explain how to implement InAppPurchase in our phonegap application .

And you may see [PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS) this project hosted on git hub.

Thanks